# php radio values won't update columns

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am writing a php function which update mysql record everything updating perfectly except radio button values i even tried to print radio values to check whether radios are working or not and i got successful results but the issues remains on position that i am unable to update radio value in my SQL

Important thing to mention here is "radio values are integers 1, 2 3 etc "

here is my html code

```
        <input type="radio" name="active_status" id="radio1" class="we-radio" value="1">
        <label for="radio1" class="we-label">Active</label>

        <input type="radio" name="active_status" id="radio2" class="we-radio" value="0">
        <label for="radio2" class="we-label">Inactive</label>

        <input type="radio" name="featured_status" id="radio3" class="we-radio" value="1">
        <label for="radio3" class="we-label">Featured</label>

        <input type="radio" name="featured_status" id="radio4" class="we-radio" value="0">
        <label for="radio4" class="we-label">Normal Video</label>
```

and its my php code

```
    $activation_vid = $_POST['active_status'];
    $featured_vid = $_POST['featured_status'];

$updates = array();
    if (!empty($activation_vid))
      $updates[] = '`vid_act_stat` ="'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$activation_vid).'"';
    if (!empty($featured_vid))
      $updates[] = '`vid_featured_stat` ="'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$featured_vid).'"';

 $updates = implode(', ', $updates); 
    $sql = "UPDATE `tblmevids` SET $updates WHERE vid_id = '$vid_edit_id'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if($result){
                $sucess = "<div class='success'>Perfect!!! Vid has been updated: ".$current_vid_code."</div>";
        } else {
                $error_display = "<div class='errormsgbox'>An error occured. Please Try Again</div>";
        }
```

Comment: What are field types in your SQL table?

Comment: As mentioned above also here too  INT(5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you select Inactive Status you pass 0 value in POST and you are using 
empty function to check which causes problem. So only when you select Active Status your query will update it for inactive Status the condition will be fail
instead using empty

```
 if (!empty($activation_vid))
```

use

```
isset() and is_numeric()
```

From PHP Manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```

it is working for me Try this

```
$activation_vid = '0';
$featured_vid = '1';
$vid_edit_id=5;
$updates = array();
    if (is_numeric($activation_vid) and isset($activation_vid))
      $updates[] = '`vid_act_stat` ="'.$activation_vid.'"';
    if (is_numeric($featured_vid) and isset($featured_vid))
      $updates[] = '`vid_featured_stat` ="'.$featured_vid.'"';

 $updates = implode(', ', $updates); 
$sql = "UPDATE `tblmevids` SET $updates WHERE vid_id = '$vid_edit_id'";
print_r($sql);
...
 //rest of your code
```

Comment: i also tried **is_numberic** and  **is_int** instead of empty but nothing works

Comment: i think it is is_numeric() not is_numberic()  http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Answer (score 0):

Since we can only guess what is wrong with your program, here are some tips:

**1.** Don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string` on integer values. Instead use `intval` function:

```
$activation_vid = intval($_POST['active_status']);
```

**2.** In your SQL statements don't put integer values in quotations:

```
$updates[] = "`vid_act_stat` = {$activation_vid}";

$sql = "UPDATE `tblmevids` SET $updates WHERE `vid_id` = $vid_edit_id";
```

**3.** This one is not actually an error but a suggestion. If you want to alternate between 0 and 1, use `checkbox` instead of `radio` buttons.

**4.** As was mentioned by "CY5", `empty` also returns `false` when the value of the variable is `0`, so you must use a defferent `if` statement to check validity of received parameters.

Comment: thanks for helping me and also giving me a great knowledge